# Failed to start Raise network interfaces, after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

ifup gets stuck, and it takes a long time at boot up and down.

```
me@K501L:~$ systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Wed 2018-08-01 13:24:54 CEST; 1h 0min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 1049 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=killed, signal=TERM)

  Process: 918 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] &&
 Main PID: 1049 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

août 01 13:19:52 K501L systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
août 01 13:19:55 K501L ifup[1049]: check cable
août 01 13:20:00 K501L ifup[1049]: /sbin/ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.enp2s0
août 01 13:24:54 K501L systemd[1]: networking.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
août 01 13:24:54 K501L systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
août 01 13:24:54 K501L systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
août 01 13:24:54 K501L systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

/etc/interfaces

```
#LAN
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.2/24 
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    dns-nameserver 10.0.0.1
```

thougt it says it didn't raise:

```
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 10.0.0.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

it works if i remove this  line from /etc/interfaces

```
dns-nameserver 10.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

it comes from avahi-deamon, since Bionic upgrade:

[avahi-daemon-check-dns.sh hang forever](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openconnect/+bug/1752411)

It can be fixed by removing avahi-deamon:

```
apt-get remove avahi-daemon
```

or by editing "/usr/lib/avahi/avahi-daemon-check-dns.sh":

in dns_has_local() replace

```
OUT=`LC_ALL=C host -t soa local. 2>&1
```

with

```
OUT=`LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/timeout 5 host -t soa local. 2>&1`
```

and you get stuck for five seconds only